# How to create variable or dynamic params in "urllib" to use in "sqlalchemy"?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, format, database-connection, urllib

How to create variable or dynamic params in "urllib" to use in "sqlalchemy"?

This is the correct format.

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
import urllib

params = urllib.parse.quote_plus("DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
                                 "SERVER=dagger;"
                                 "DATABASE=test;"
                                 "UID=user;"
                                 "PWD=password")

engine = sa.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}".format(params))
```

I've tried to create a variable "a,b,c,d" to include "SERVER, DATABASE, UID, PWD"

The script is like this but it doesn't work.

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
import urllib

a = 'dagger'
b = 'test'
c = 'user'
d = 'password'

params = urllib.parse.quote_plus("DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
                                 "SERVER={};".format(a)
                                 "DATABASE={};".format(b)
                                 "UID={};".format(c)
                                 "PWD={}".format(d))

engine = sa.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}".format(params))
```

Answer (score 0):

change it to :

```
params = urllib.parse.quote_plus(f"DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};SERVER={a};DATABASE={b};UID={c};PWD={d}")
```

but your current objects arent valid for quote_plus

looks like [urllib docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html)

> urllib.parse.quote_plus(string, safe='', encoding=None, errors=None)
> Like quote(), but also replace spaces with plus signs, as required for
> quoting HTML form values when building up a query string to go into a
> URL. Plus signs in the original string are escaped unless they are
> included in safe. It also does not have safe default to '/'.
>
> Example: quote_plus('/El Niño/') yields '%2FEl+Ni%C3%B1o%2F'.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for solution, it was solve

I use this

```
params = urllib.parse.quote_plus("DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"+
                                 "SERVER={};".format(a)+
                                 "DATABASE={};".format(b)+
                                 "UID={};".format(c)+
                                 "PWD={}".format(d))
```

Comment: i perefer do not concat strings (performance issue)